# QGIS algorithms do not work on copies of shapefiles?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, saga, sextante

I'm using QGIS 2.6.0. I'm trying to run various algorithms such as "SAGA/Shapes-points/remove duplicates" & "SAGA/Shapes-Grid/Add grid values to points" through the sextant toolbox.

When I run these algorithms on a shapefile (initially created via the QGIS option "Create a Layer from a Delimited Text File" and then saving the output as a shapefile), it works fine. However, if I create a copy of the shapefile through QGIS (i.e. using Save As) even with no changes (e.g. same coordinate system) and try to run these algorithms using the same input parameters, it fails. An example of the error that appears is as follows:

```
"Oooops! The following output layers could not be open
Result: C:\Users\stephen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\bf494593f4a44905bb4ec0bbe0a7f847\RESULT.shp
The above files could not be opened, which probably indicates that they were not correctly produced by the executed algorithm
Checking the log information might help you see why those layers were not created as expected
This algorithm requires SAGA to be run. A test to check if SAGA is correctly installed and configured in your system has been performed, with the following result:
SAGA seems to be correctly installed and configured"
```

The log output is as follows:

```
"SAGA execution console output

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps\saga

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin>PATH=PATH;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps\saga;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin>saga_cmd shapes_points "Remove Duplicate Points" -POINTS "E:/Studies/Data/Consolidated/Records_06092014_Copy.shp" -FIELD "Precision" -METHOD 0 -NUMERIC 1 -RESULT "C:\Users\stephen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\bf494593f4a44905bb4ec0bbe0a7f847\RESULT.shp"
_____________________________________________
#####   ##   #####    ##
###     ###  ##       ###
###   # ## ##  #### # ##
### ##### ##    # #####
##### #   ##  ##### #   ##
_____________________________________________

library path:   C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps\saga\modules
library name:   shapes_points
module name :   Remove Duplicate Points
author      :   O.Conrad (c) 2008
_____________________________________________
go...

Load shapes: E:/Studies/Data/Consolidated/Records_06092014_Copy.shp...

ready

okay

Remove Duplicate Points: Invalid parameters!

Shapes: Points

error: executing module [Remove Duplicate Points]

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin>exit"
```

Just wondering whether anyone has come across a similar problem and if they have found a solution?

Comment: Not come across this issue. What about copying/pasting the shapefiles outside of QGIS and then run the algorithm?

Comment: Hi Joseph, copying and pasting outside of QGIS, doesn't seem to fix the problem, however the algorithms do work when I create a new shapefile within QGIS and paste the features into it. But if I then make a copy of the new shape file (using the save as), again the algorithms fail? I've tried checking for geometry errors, reviewed the files metadata against the original for differences, however can't see any problems? Very strange! Thanks for your assist